# CSS-Only Autosuggest?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to make a CSS-only autosuggest and I need help with it please. I want to automatically show/hide suggestions in case they match / don't match a text-input value (or similar).
I found this JSFiddle being a good example: https://jsfiddle.net/zsUuK/6/

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="autosuggest">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <div class="dropdown">
      <ul class="result">
        <li>Suggestion</li>
        <li>Not to be here</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first suggestion would be hidden by default and made visible when typing in "S" e.g.

**Please note** that I know how to do the autosuggest with JavaScript and also simply with HTML autocomplete="on". My question is, if there is **any way** to do it only with CSS, even in very tricky ways.

Looking forward for your answers and already a big Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to get the value of an input using CSS so there is no way to do this. Why would you not use JavaScript? This is exactly the type of task it is designed for.

Comment: Hi @Turnip, I will probably be providing a website where a lot of people have JavaScript disabled. Also I prefer JS over CSS when possible. I got compromised by the idea of a CSS autosuggest when I saw that CSS keyloggers exist: https://jsfiddle.net/hcbogdan/6hmm2z47/ (Safe link)

Comment: I don't think that example is doing what you think it is. Those type of keylogger attacks, similar to this: https://github.com/maxchehab/CSS-Keylogging, make it possible to send data to a remote resource. I can't think of any way that it could help you here.

Comment: I didn't mean the CSS keylogger trick as a solution for a CSS autosuggest. But as I surely don't know every CSS trick (like the CSS keylogger for example) I'd like to ask for help of more advanced coders.

Comment: Short answer, It's not possible.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use some kind of jquery for it here is a function to show/hide suggestions:

```
function mus_pl_filter(element) {
var value = $(element).val();
$(".result > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

}

Trigger this function on keyup:

```
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" onkeyup="mus_pl_filter(this)">
```

Comment: sorry for input its wrong use : 
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" onkeyup="mus_pl_filter(this)">

Comment: yes i did, but i had this solution in mind so i share it with you. i think its not possible with css only.

Comment: Best practice is to create an instantiable autosuggest object - and assign a trigger method of an instance to the "input" event of every element with class "autosuggest".